# Azure Functions: ICollector<T> vs IAsyncCollector<T>

Tags: azure-webjobs, azure-webjobssdk, azure-functions

What's the difference between `ICollector<T>` and `IAsyncCollector<T>` in Azure Functions when writing C# functions (also applies to WebJobs)?

I understand from the samples that these are interfaces I can use to bind a function parameter to an output binding. I also understand that the two interfaces have non-async and async method signatures accordingly (i.e. `ICollector<T>.Add(item)` and `IAsyncCollector<T>.AddAsync(item)`). But what do they do under the covers? Do they actually post data to the output binding, or is it internally buffered and flushed at the end of function execution (in which case, why would there by an `AddAsync` method)?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

`ICollector<T>.Add(item)` will always perform the add operation against the underlying service **immediately**. E.g. the implementation for the Queue binding will enqueue messages immediately as they are added.

`IAsyncCollector<T>.AddAsync(item)` behavior varies from binding to binding, based on whether the underlying service supports **batching**. In such cases, `AddAsync` may only actually save the added items to be **flushed later** by the corresponding `IAsyncCollector<T>.FlushAsync` method. When a function completes successfully `FlushAsync` will be called automatically. You can allow the auto-flush behavior to flush for you, or you may choose to call `FlushAsync` manually in your function as you need to.

Batching can allow the binding to interact with the underlying service in the most efficient way possible. E.g. for Azure Tables, multiple entities can be updated/persisted in a single batch operation.

Comment: Except it looks like most bindings DON'T support batching (see https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk/issues/921). ServiceBus doesn't batch for example!